# Swift inheritance issue. How to get appropriate class object

Tags: swift

I have two classes (to simplify I drop other filed the object is more complicated then the Person):

```
class Person
{
  var name: String = "Default name"

  init(object: PersonEntity)
  {
    name = object.daysMask
  }
}

class Employer: Person
{

}
```

I have function that configure for me a person

```
func getConiguratedPerson(name: String) -> Person
{
  let person = Person()
  person.name = name
}
```

In case if I want to get `Person` I simple do this:

```
let person = getConiguratedPerson("Alex")
```

but what if I need `Employer` instead and I want to use this function as well

```
let employer = getConiguratedPerson("Alex") // returns Person as expected but need to have employer instead.
```

In Objective-C we can simple do this:

```
Employer *employer = Employer([self getConiguratedPerson:"Alex"]) if I remember.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is the `getConfiguredPerson` function. You want an initializer. Initializers return your own class, which is exactly what you want.

```
class Person {
  var name: String = "Default name"

  init(name: String) {
      self.name = name
  }

  init(object: PersonEntity) {
      self.init(object.daysMask)
  }
}

class Employer: Person {}
```

Now to create a person, you just use `Person(name: "Alex")` and to get an employer you use `Employer(name: "Alex")`.

Note that this is true in ObjC as well. You shouldn't have `getConfiguredPerson` there either. You'd should have `[Person initWithName:]`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how to create factory method then? if I don't need method which is similar to factory method pattern. or for example cell for row at index path also returns UITableViewCell, but you can configure any cell if you want

Comment: For cellForRow you generally need both generics and an as! cast. For the most general case of "class returning Self", that is not possible with classes due to inheritance problems (search for "protocol returning Self" and you should find the many discussions of this on SO). There is no one general answer in any case. You need an explicit question addressing what you're trying to do. In the case you describe, init is correct. For what specific problem do you want a factory?

Comment: In particular, you can't "configure any cell you want" in most code. You need to know what kind of cell you're returning (otherwise, how would you configure it?). If you know, then generics are usually the answer.

Comment: I got it, yea it's nice answer I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can't use upcasting here, because configured person is not of Employee type, but of Person type. To achieve the desired result I would suggest something like this:

```
class Person {
    var name = "name"

    required init() { }
}

class Employee: Person { }

func getPerson<T: Person>(name: String) -> T {
    let person = T()
    person.name = name
    return person
}

let employee: Employee = getPerson("Alex")
```

or this if type of object returning by factory method depends on input:

```
func getPerson(name: String) -> Person {
    if name != "Alex" {
        return Person()
    }

    return Employee()
}

let employee = getPerson("Alex") as! Employee
```